# How to convert a common Gradle script to Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am stuck on converting a common Gradle script to Gradle Kotlin DSL as it applies a custom plugin on its own so that I can't somehow make it working. What I am exactly trying to achieve this;

android-defaults.gradle (Old way - working)

```
apply plugin: 'libraryCommonPlugin' -> the custom plugin

android {

    defaultConfig {
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

And I tried to convert this to Kotlin DSL like so;

android-default.gradle.kts (New way - not working)

```
plugins {
    id("libraryCommonPlugin") -> the custom plugin
}

android {

    defaultConfig {
        // other stuff
    }   
}
```

However, this doesn't compile at all and I am getting below error;

> Expression 'android' cannot be invoked as a function. The function
> 'invoke()' is not found

Yes, I am aware of that I don't apply `com.android.application` plugin but when I apply it so then I am getting another error;

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id:
> 'libraryCommonPlugin'] was not found in any of the following sources:

But I don't want to have a `com.android.application` plugin or whatsoever with it cause both `application` and `library` scripts will benefit from the above common script like so;

**a.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    id("commons.android-defaults")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android")
}

dependencies {
}
```

**app.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    id("commons.android-defaults")
    id("com.android.application")
    id("kotlin-android")
}

dependencies {
}
```

Do you have any solution for that particular case?

Comment: Can you share the GitHub repo?

Comment: @JavierSegoviaCordoba oh this is from a private repo but I'll create a sample for you and update you here! Thanks.